# Cannot find module 'usr/src/client/NPM' | DOCKER

Tags: javascript, docker

I made an image using a Dockerfile and I'm trying to run it using Docker Desktop, but I'm getting this error. I can't figure out what the problem is, has anyone experienced this?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/client

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --force
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3006
CMD ["NPM", "RUN", "START"]
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymG5U.png)

I don't event know what to do)

Comment: Linux is case-sensitive. Fix the case => `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be it, but CMD calls are case sensitive, so try:

```
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

But you might also want to try using the RUN command instead of CMD:

```
RUN npm run start
```

Comment: _"CMD calls are case sensitive"_ It depends on the shell and the OS. It's not always case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thanks. But now I have another problem: I can't connect to localhost:3006 now, can you help?

Comment: @dmitrich0 Not without more context, sorry. Maybe check out https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp